# Как перевести вертикальную таблицу в горизонтальную?

Tags: mysql, sql

Что имеется?
Имеется таблица такого вида

```
+----+--------------+-------+--------------+
| id | product_name | count | warehouse_id |
+----+--------------+-------+--------------+
|  1 | Puperproduct |    10 |            1 |
|  2 | Puperproduct |    15 |            2 |
|  3 | Puperproduct |    12 |            3 |
+----+--------------+-------+--------------+
```

Что нужно получить?
Нужно получить макс и мин количество товаров с ихними складами.

```
+-----+---------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+------------------+
| id  | product_name  | min_count | min_warehouse_id | max_count | max_warehouse_id |
+-----+---------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+------------------+
|  1  | Puperproduct  |        10 |                1 |        15 |                2 |
+-----+---------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Что у меня получилось?
Получилось:

```
select 
    id
    , product_name
    , min(count) as min_count
    , max(count) as max_count
from table
group by product_name

+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | product_name | min_count | max_count |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | Puperproduct |        10 |        15 |
+----+--------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Как взять ид складов? Количество записей около 800К. Mysql 5.5

Comment: Ну так добавьте `MIN(warehouse_id) as min_warehouse_id, MAX(warehouse_id) as max_warehouse_id` вам же это нужно?

Comment: не, там судя по примеру нужно ид склада, на котором `count == max_count`

Comment: @zRrr Вот проблема именно в этом. MAX(warehouse_id) я просто получу макс ид склада. А нужно ид склада где товаров минимально и максимально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собираем в одну строку `count` дополненный, скажем, до 10 символов и соответствующий ему `warehouse_id`, берем от этой строки min/max и потом из этого вырезаем склад обратно и преобразуем в числовой вид:

```
select id, product_name,
       max(count) as max_count, min(count) as min_count,
       substr(min(concat(lpad(count,10,'0'),warehouse_id)),11)+0 min_warehouse_id,
       substr(max(concat(lpad(count,10,'0'),warehouse_id)),11)+0 max_warehouse_id
  from table
 group by product_name
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/048a1/2 -  неправда ваша

Comment: @splash58 Ну случайно один max вместо min написал ... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/048a1/5

Comment: я ж не против :)

Comment: а что-нить такое не помешает? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1704e/4

Comment: @splash58 Нет, а чем оно может помешать. Плохо будет только если count окажется более 10 знаков. Но тогда надо будет просто увеличить  количество знаков в lpad, поэтому в тексте и написано "_дополненный, скажем, до 10_"

Comment: я просто не настолько спец, вот и засомневался, не будут ли они сравниваться, как числа, а не строки :) А вообще, подход любопытный

Comment: @splash58 lpad и последующие функции возвращают тип "строка", min/max не будет пытаться привести тип к числу перед сравнением.

Comment: @splash58, спасибо за ссылочку. любопытно

Comment: Очень интересный подход. Очень. Но больше похоже на хак, хотя и работает.
Надо будет сравнить по времени с подходом от @cheops

Comment: Но похоже, к сожалению, такой подход сработает только для чисел, но не для строк......

Comment: @AlmaZ Не вижу особой разницы, вопрос лишь в том, что бы зашить правильную максимальную длину. И если сортировка идет изначально по строке, то использовать rpad вместо lpad и дополнять пробелами

Comment: Работает! Ничего не понимаю..... Функция Max берет изначальные цифры для сравнения?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97ef1/1

Comment: @AlmaZ Разумеется. Вы substr уберите и увидите строку, которая получается перед вырезкой данных. там count пишется в формате '0000000012' и после него слитно данные. min/max сортирует этот как строки

Comment: @Mike Так и сделал http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5bad9/1

Comment: То есть MAX считает слева направо. Даже 01099999999999999 меньше чем 011! Хотя это строка а не цифра.

Comment: @AlmaZ да, именно так, он же это сравнивает по правилам сравнения строк, а не чисел. А строки именно так и сравниваются. по больше/меньше первого неодинакового символа. собственно для этого и дополнение нулями слева, что бы и размер фиксированный был и сравнение правильно шло

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  gr.id AS id
  , gr.product_name AS product_name
  , gr.min_count AS min_count
  , min.warehouse_id AS min_warehouse_id
  , gr.max_count AS max_count
  , max.warehouse_id AS max_warehouse_id
FROM
  (SELECT
      id
      , product_name
      , min(count) AS min_count
      , max(count) AS max_count
  FROM
    table AS main
  GROUP BY
    product_name) AS gr
LEFT JOIN
  table AS min
ON
  gr.product_name = min.product_name AND
  gr.min_count = min.count
LEFT JOIN
  table AS max
ON
  gr.product_name = max.product_name AND
  gr.max_count = max.count;
```

Однако лучше посмотреть анализатором на продуктовой базе, не будет ли несколько запросов дешевле.

Answer (score 0):

А если просто `select * from table order by count desc` использовать? Тогда "сверху" будет макс кол-во, а "снизу" - мин.

Comment: И чем это поможет? Нужно получить результат одной строкой.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть по-идиотски и очень не оптимально (Впрочем, этого в условии не было), но вроде бы работает:

```
SELECT tmp.product_name,
 tmp.min_count,
 t2.warehouse_id as min_warehouse_id,
        tmp.max_count,
         t3.warehouse_id as max_warehouse_id 
FROM (
SELECT 
     t1.id
    , t1.product_name
    , MIN(COUNT) AS min_count
    , MAX(COUNT) AS max_count
FROM test1 t1
GROUP BY t1.product_name) tmp
JOIN test1 t2 ON tmp.product_name = t2.product_name AND tmp.min_count = t2.count
JOIN test1 t3 ON tmp.product_name = t3.product_name AND tmp.max_count = t3.count
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему никто не вспоминает про переменные в MySQL?
Вариант от Mike будет работать вероятно быстрее, но всё же предложу альтернативу:

```
SELECT id, product_name, count, warehouse_id, 
  CASE WHEN count = @I THEN 'MIN' ELSE 'MAX' END row_type
FROM(
  SELECT *
    ,@I := CASE WHEN @I<count AND @I>=0 THEN @I ELSE count END min_count 
    ,@J := CASE WHEN @J>count AND @J>=0 THEN @J ELSE count END max_count 
  FROM thetable, 
    (SELECT @I := -1, @J:= -1)T
)T
WHERE count IN (@I, @J)
```

Тут выведутся все склады с максимальным и минимальным значением поля count.
На результат можно посмотреть здесь:

[ссылка на http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/58135/4)